# Increment z-index for each div

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

I am working on a design where divs overlay each other and I do to separately increment `z-index` by 1 for each member of a class. And I feel like there is a better way to do it with `jquery`.

What I want is something like for each div with the class `section` to have a `z-index` greater by than the previous but not being thrown off by divs which are not members of the specific class such as

```
<div class="section" style="z-index:1">Lorem</div>
<div class="section" style="z-index:2">Lorem</div>
<div id="OutOfPlaceDiv">Foo</div>
<div class="section" style="z-index:3">Lorem</div>
```

Comment: `$('.section').each(function(index, el) { $(el).css('z-index', index + starting_z-index_value); });` Replace `starting_z-index_value` with value from which you want to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `each` method to iterate through the elements with that class.

```
$('.section').each(function(index) {
  $(this).css("z-index", index);
});
```

This will set the indexes to `0, 1, 2` etc. If you want to start at something other than `0`:

```
var offset = 1;
$('.section').each(function(index) {
  $(this).css("z-index", offset + index);
});
```

Comment: Working fine for me. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: have you got jquery ? see my answer.

Comment: Ah nevermind, I was looking at the wrong copy... Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty css hack but simple and effective if you have just dozen of div:

```
.section:nth-child(1) { z-index: 1; }
.section:nth-child(2) { z-index: 2; }
.section:nth-child(3) { z-index: 3; }
...
```